# run reactor in a loop (python twisted)

Tags: python, twisted, reactor, twisted.internet

There is an external function (another module) that uses Twisted, so in order for it to work I need to call reactor.run()
However I want to call that function multiple times. How can I do it? (I get ReactorNotRestartable error)

Answer (score 0):

If there's an API you want to call and the implementation of that API calls `reactor.run` then you cannot call it more than once.

Perhaps there is an alternate API you can call which does everything *except* for calling `reactor.run`.  Then you can manage the `reactor.run` call in your own code (making sure to only call it once) while calling that alternate API as many times as you like.

Answer (score 0):

You can run the `twisted` function in a background thread using [`crochet`][1], then bring the results into the foreground process when the execution finishes. Just don't execute `reactor.stop()` because that might mess things up. Also, `crochet` will take care of stopping the reactor.